# How to find the connected system on the server through java coding?

Tags: java

I have one java application. That application works like getting the PC informations(Hardware and profile details). So I want to get the which system connected on the server when that application running on the server. How its possible? I dont have about this. Give me the idea's about this.

Simply server is parent means i want to find child system's through java coding.

Comment: so if i understand you, you want to show netstat type information through java? Java doesn't support this directly, you would have to execute native code thru jni, or executing an external process, and each platform would potentially have different commands to do this.

Comment: Is it possible get the connected ports on the server through java?

Comment: no in general java can't obtain information from other running processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 little ideas maybe some of them can inspire you or give you some tips.

**Idea 1:**

Detect and log the IP addresses and the time the users connect to your application.

Something like this i think should allow you to get the IP:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
 throws IOException {
   String ip = req.getRemoteAddr();
   Date date = new Date();
   MyLogger.log(ip,date);
  }
```

If req.getRemoteAddr() dont work try(The clients IP has to be somewhere on the header):

> request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")
>   See [Link](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/x-forwarded-for-http-header.html)

**Idea 2:**

About knowing the type of system that is connected to the server, i think [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) can do some of that for you if the remote system allows it. I never used it but i think you can do certain monitoring thinks with it.

**Idea 3:**

I think the best way to detect information about the clients machine, is having an application running in that concrete client machine.
An applet. I am not sure about this one, but if i remember good applets execute on client side, maybe you could find the way to put one in your web-app so it can detect information about the client system easily and then forward it back to the app server.(As i said i am not sure if this is possible)

**Idea 4**

Find third party software, maybe a web service(Some kind of advanced whois web service) that gets the info for you when you send just a parameter(exmample: Ip address)

**Update**

This api might help you: [jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/)

P.S also having a quick look to the [sockets chapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) of the java tutorials, can also become handy.

Comment: Is there any other way?  All PC's are connected with single server system. Is it possible through LAN connection? Totally i'm confused.

Comment: Aha ok i think now i understand a bit better your problem. Some of the comments mentioned on some java limitations regarding to retrieving information. You can maybe try to find a work around. Have a look at jpcap it is a java API for networking. Maybe is handy. Ill update the link in my answer above.